# QDesktopServices truncates the # sign in a path

Tags: qt, qt5

If I have a # sign in my path, QDesktopServices truncates the string resulting in everything behind and including this sign beeing removed. Using the approach below results in inserting a %23 sign which also fails opening the file. I want that the string is copied into the address field as I defined (with a #).

```
QString file = "F:/the_path/to_the_/generated#_html_file.html";
QUrl test = QUrl::fromLocalFile(file);
// gives url="file:///F:/the_path/to_the_/generated%23_html_file.html";
QDesktopServices::openUrl(test); //unable to open
```

Comment: When you put the text in your browser: `file:///F:/the_path/to_the_/generated#_html_file.html` file opens?

Comment: Try to screen #: `\#`

Comment: If I copy and paste the value of my QString manually into my browser it works. Screening with "\#" does not work and creates a !warning: C4129: '#': unrecognized character escape sequence".